# Unable to Boot up ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am unable to start Elastic Search on my Linux Machine.
When I run ./elasticsearch command, the process exits within 20 seconds with below error.

```
$ ./elasticsearch -v
Skipping security auto configuration because it appears that security is already configured.

ERROR: Elasticsearch exited unexpectedly
```

Also there are no relevant logs in logs folder, just GC logs which don't provide any hint.
Even -v verbose option is not giving any pointers as to why the service is unable to start.

How can I debug this better and fine the cause of the failure ?

Comment: Any chance to change the log level? I'd assume that within 20 seconds there should at least be some info or debug logs which probably are just filtered. Besides that, did you check the JVM options that ES is using? Does your JVM support those (example: some JVMs don't support more than 2g heap - not sure if this is related to 32-bit JVMs but might be)? Does your machine enough resources like memory?

Comment: do you have enough memory for Elasticsearch process? where are you running it locally or AWS? also how you installed your Elasticsearch ?

Comment: @Amit-ESenthusiast  I am running it locally. I downloaded tar file/extracted it and then running ./elasticsearch command from bin folder.
Not sure on memory as I am not seeing any error or exception at all

Comment: @Thomas As per the documentation I am using -v verbose option to print more logs but that also is not providing any more failure information. I am not sure if it is problem with Heap as I have seen some examples where ES will throw OutOfMemory exception which can be seen in logs as well. But here in my case I don't see any exception.
I am using JDK 18 which is bundled with ES binary itself. And it is x64 env and ES binary is also of same architecture.

Comment: @leo11 did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @ktb92677 Yes I was able to. ES was running out of RAM.
After closing some apps I was able to bring ES up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like OP's issue was different from mine, but the error it produced was the same. Incase anyone else stumbles across this incredibly annoying issue...

Basically I was trying to install the elastic stack and Grafana on the same LXC container in proxmox. Grafana and elastic cannot be installed on the same LXC container because Grafana requires nesting to be enabled, but elastic doesn't work when nesting is enabled.

So long answer short, disable nesting on the LXC container.